# Is it possible to have two external monitors (without using the built in one) on Lenovo G560 laptop?

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, lenovo-laptop

I'd like to connect two monitors, and run off both of them without using the main laptop monitor (it's too small to bother with once I've got the 17" ones attached).

I have only one monitor port.

Is it possible to get both monitors connected?  If so, what's the cheapest way of achieving this?

I've seen other posts relating to multiple monitors, but don't know how to tell what applies to my laptop, and what doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use kensington Multi Display to have two monitors connected to my laptop.

It uses the USB port.

Here are some you can buy:

https://www.google.com/search?q=kensington+multi+display&tbm=shop&aq=f